# displayName is not populate from LDAP with WASLTPARealm

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

we integrate Datapower with Worklight using WASLTPARealm.
After login we expect the method `WL.Client.getUserName()` return the user name as it appears in LDAP.
this methods return `null`.
also after login the field displayName is also `null`.

this our ldap config in `server.xml`

```
<ldapRegistry baseDN="DC=Me" bindDN="CN=YO" bindPassword="XXX" host="1.1.1.1" id="ActiveDirectoryLDAP" ignoreCase="true" ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" loginProperty="uid" port="389" realm="net" referal="follow">

    <activedFilters groupFilter="....." groupIdMap="*:cn" groupMemberIdMap="memberOf:member" userFilter="..." userIdMap="*:sAMAccountName">
    </activedFilters>

    <contextPool enabled="true" initialSize="1" maxSize="0" preferredSize="3" timeout="0s" waitTime="3000ms"/>

    <ldapCache>
        <attributesCache enabled="true" size="4000" sizeLimit="2000" timeout="1200s"/>
        <searchResultsCache enabled="true" resultsSizeLimit="1000" size="2000" timeout="600s"/>
    </ldapCache>
</ldapRegistry>

<ltpa expiration="120" keysFileName="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/ltpa.keystore" keysPassword="XXXX"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details here? What does your authenticationConfig.xml look like? At what point are you trying to get the username? After the user logs in and the challenge handler finished doing its job? Did all authentication complete before trying to get the user name?

Answer (score 0):

The username and displayname will be populated on a client side only AFTER successful authentication. Maybe this thread will help - [IBM Worklight : WL.Client.getUserName Fails to retrieve userIdentity immediately after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770854)