# IBM Worklight: Not get response after adapter-based auth successfully

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

Worklight Studio 6.0.0.2; Worklight Server 6.0.0; Hybrid app on Android;

Recently, I found another strange behavior with Worklight Adapter-based authentication. It is that the #7 step below doesn't happen for me (The following 7 steps are copies from Anton's one answer) in case of that I passed the auth at the beginning, and then run app in the background. After Worklight session expired, return app to the foreground. At this time, the first request won't get response when re-auth with WL server.

1. You're making request#1 to the server (let's say invoke procedure)
2. You're getting response with authRequired:true
3. You're submitting auth data
4. You're getting authRequred:false
5. You're calling submitSuccess()
6. WL framework automatically re-invokes request#1
7. You're getting response for request#1

Android logs:

```
D/NONE(19720): Request [https://xxx/android/composite]
D/NONE(19720): auth required: true
D/NONE(19720): re-submit custom auth
D/NONE(19720): Request [https://xxx/../../invoke]
D/NONE(19720): auth required: false
D/NONE(19720): response.responseJSON: {"isSuccessful":true,"authRequired":false}
D/NONE(19720): Request [https://xxx/android/composite]
```

See? Not get response of "composite" request. Actually, I also don't get response of other #1 request in some case, which causes my app cannot proceed. In this case, I have to send two same requests: one goes away without reponse; another one works well.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Updates:

Via PC browser, I found the request of #6 step got 403 error...;

My some codes:

```
pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){
        var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;
        var loginForm = registry.byId("loginPage");

        if(authRequired){
            WL.Logger.debug("auth required: " + authRequired);
            if(response.responseJSON.errorMessage != null){
                mBase.showProgressIndicator();
                loginForm.hintNode.innerHTML = response.responseJSON.errorMessage;
                loginForm.usernameNode.domNode.focus();
            }else{
                WL.Logger.debug("re-submit custom auth");
                pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.doCustomAuth(loginForm.usernameNode.get('value'), loginForm.passwordNode.get('value'));
            }
        }else if(authRequired == false){
            WL.Logger.debug("auth required: " + authRequired);
            if(!pushAppRealmChallengeHandler._authFinished){
                pushAppRealmChallengeHandler._authFinished = true;

                ...

                pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
            }else {
                WL.Logger.debug("response.responseJSON: " + dojo.toJson(response.responseJSON));
                pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
            }
        }
    };

pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.doCustomAuth = function(userName, password) {  
        var loginForm = registry.byId("loginPage");
        var invocationData = {
            adapter : "AuthAdapter",
            procedure : "submitAuthentication",
            parameters : [Base64.encode(userName), Base64.encode(password), userName, pushAppRealmChallengeHandler._authFinished]
        };
        pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {
            onFailure : function() {
                mBase.showProgressIndicator();
                loginForm.hintNode.innerHTML = Messages.WLErrMsg;//netErrMsg;
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Instead of steps, why not add the actual adapter implementation and challenge handler code? that way, it could be *debugged* to some degree...

Comment: You also did not link to whichever answer Anton provided you.

Comment: The link to Anton's answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770854/ibm-worklight-wl-client-getusername-fails-to-retrieve-useridentity-immediately

Comment: Can you show your Adapter code as well? Both the AuthAdapter and the original adapter you are trying to reach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team fixed this issue by changing the configuration of mobileSecurityTest. An reason is that one of test realm doesn't give the response. So, my team remove that test realm belong to mobileSecurityTest.

Old

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest">
    <testUser realm="PushAppRealm"/>
    <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
</mobileSecurityTest>
```

New

```
<customSecurityTest name="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest">
    <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm"/>
    <test realm="PushAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" />
</customSecurityTest>
```